# Firebase + Node.js: Error: The XMLHttpRequest compatibility library was not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

Firebase + Node.js

On iOS:

1. Installed Node.js
2. npm install firebase --save
3. node test.js

Where test.js is a very simply script to connect to Firebase:

```
var firebase = require("firebase/app");
require("firebase/auth");

var config = {
   ...
};

var app = firebase.initializeApp(config); // Works fine
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(…); // Throws error
```

The error thrown is

```
Error: The XMLHttpRequest compatibility library was not found.
```

What am I overlooking? Thanks.

Comment: So you ran the code in node or in browser?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: No browser.  CLI.  Just running the node JavaScript engine executing directly as a client.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same issue by using Angularfire2 with Universal Server Side rendering. I've solved it by adding the `xmlhttprequest` to my `server.js` file.

Just like this:

`npm install xmlhttprequest --save`

and adding it like:

`global.XMLHttpRequest = require('xmlhttprequest').XMLHttpRequest;`

or

```
global['XMLHttpRequest'] = require('xmlhttprequest').XMLHttpRequest;
```

Maybe it helps someone!

Comment: I did this, forgot about it, and then spent three days trying to debug a firebase storage upload problem. This package was interfering with firebases' ability to upload docs. Beware.

Comment: @orlandter Update your answer with some content, hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 12):

Mmmhhh.  Interesting.  By changing the multiple 'require' lines (taken from the Firebase docs) into a single:

```
var firebase = require("firebase");
```

It started working just fine.

Answer (score 5):

For **Firebase** Server side rendering to work properly you need to install:

- `npm i xmlhttprequest ws -s`
- `npm i bufferutil utf-8-validate -s`

Then on the **server.ts** file(found at the root folder) add:

```
(global as any).XMLHttpRequest = require('xmlhttprequest').XMLHttpRequest;
```

Read on more on this tutorial: [here](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/server-side-rendering-firebase-angular-universal/)

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it after 2 days of trying hard!

You should not put the firebase code in the constructor. Move it the componentDidMount() method. And move the functions above the constructor.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: This did indeed help, I thought. I am using Sapper, but the principles should be the same. Unfortunately, what it seemed to do is only run that code on the frontend. Is it possible this is what happened in your case too?