# Cannot access dynamic url from brower in Angular 7 universal

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-universal

With angular 7  universal, I'm run on client server with command:

> npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr

I have homepage with list products and product-detail with paramn getting from homepage.

In homepage.ts, to redirect to product-detail, I'm using:

> this.router.navigate(['/product-detail', id]);

On brower, the url like: http://localhost:4000/product-detail/1

And product-detail page still loading But when I refresh page or access with url on brower, it not working.

I'm don't know how to fix that. Anyone can help? Please.

Comment: Any error in the console server side? Or client side?

Comment: Hi David. I try to add console.log('Check flow') in product-detail.component.ts - In case : this.router.navigate(['/product-detail', id]); - It log in cosole of browser.But in case access in url brower, It show in console terminal of visual code.

Comment: But in the console where you run `npm run serve:ssr`, you have no errors?

Comment: It work fine, hard to know it

Comment: @David I add console.log(errs) after call API has errors "Error: The XMLHttpRequest compatibility library was not found. - code: 'auth/internal-error' - message: 'The XMLHttpRequest compatibility library was not found.' "

Comment: Are you using firebase? That may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41214625/firebase-node-js-error-the-xmlhttprequest-compatibility-library-was-not-foun

Comment: Hi @David, I find solution in my case from https://fireship.io/lessons/angular-universal-firebase/ - I add 2 line (global as any).WebSocket = require('ws');
(global as any).XMLHttpRequest = require('xmlhttprequest').XMLHttpRequest; in serve.ts --- Now, I tried to setup dynamic meta tag with title and description fetch from DB. But facebook crawler only know meta tag from index.html. Do you have solution for this? Thanks you.

Comment: In chrome browser, when F12 to check element I can see meta tag update. But when I viewpage source, nothing to change.

Comment: That's a different question

Comment: @David, maybe I dont pass that issue. When I using httpClient to fetch data from API, it alway errors. Message errors look like: (node:16776) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead ----- "ProgressEvent {
  type: 'error',
  target:
   XMLHttpRequest {..............."

Comment: I think my case like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49355650/angular5-server-side-rendering-external-api-data-service-does-not-work-in-ssr